# Why a localDate field is "nullable = false"

Tags: jhipster

When I generate a table with field LocalDate, it will be mandatory.

```
@Column(name = "supported_date", nullable = false)
private LocalDate supportedDate;
```

I don't understand this rule.

Comment: I think it makes sense as a safe default.

Answer (score 0):

It's right there in the `@Column` annotation: [`nullable = false` means that the column is not nullable,](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/Column.html#nullable()) which means that it cannot contain null values, which means that the column is required.

Comment: I understand the technical implementation.
But I don't understand the "phylosophical" rule for Jhipster.

ex : I can have a field "name" and "code" null but not an LocalDate field.
For me "null or not" is an use case.

Comment: I don't understand what you're saying. If you don't want to require the `LocalDate` field, just make it `nullable = true`.